# simple dom question

Tags: dom, nodes, selectnodes, google-chrome-devtools

say I have

```
<div id="searchform">
  <div style="float:right">
    <a href="~">Advanced Search</a>
  </div>
  <div id="resultStats">
    About 5 trillion results
  </div>
</div>
```

I just need to change the first child to float: bottom instead of float:right.

Thank you guys for your help! I really mean it! So when I enter this into the chrome console, it doesn't work. Within my Sweet Search ext, it says "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null"

```
document.getElementById("subform_ctrl").childNodes[0].style = 'float:bottom';
```

(Note: id is 'subform_ctrl')

Comment: I've never heard of float bottom.

Comment: you have never heard of it because it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('#searchform *:first-child').style.float = 'bottom'
```

**BUT I don't think float = bottom is valid.**

So, what is it that you are really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('searchform').childNodes[0].style = 'float:bottom';
```

Comment: That will return a text node (if there is even one line break in there) and I'm not sure but I don't think you can set the style that way.

Answer (score 0):

Float: bottom! (top?!)

[image]

**Float: bottom? Sure!**

[image]

Next release I am gonna delete 'About' trade 'results' for 'in' and delete 'seconds' and only show the seconds if it's longer than .5